# Creating a UINavigationController for the first UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

It seems there are several approaches to creating a `UINavigationController` to be the very first controller. Perhaps the easiest way is to simply click the View Controller in Storyboard and embed it in a navigation controller. But I would like to know the best approach when doing this only in code.

You can subclass `UINavigationController`, import the first view controller, and in `viewDidLoad` `alloc` and `init` an instance, then add it as a `childViewController`. In Storyboard replace the default view controller with a navigation controller and set the class to your nav controller. Note that in previous versions of iOS it was not recommended to subclass `UINavigationController`.

Or you can create another `UIViewController`, `alloc init` the first view controller, then `alloc init` a `UINavigationController` with that view controller as the root, add the navigation controller as a child view controller of this view controller, and add the navigation controller's view as a subview of this view controller's view. Change the class of the view controller in Storyboard. This is an awkward setup though, because you create a view controller whose purpose is to add a nav controller but it's not a nav controller itself.

I've read about another approach which involves creating the `UINavigationController` in the `AppDelegate`. Perhaps there are even more solutions.

What is the most appropriate approach, working in the latest development environment, targeting iOS 8+?

Comment: "Best" is a subjective thing. What specific situation are you interested in? Are you talking about using no storyboard, or having a storyboard with an initial view controller that you want to embed in a navigation controller?

Comment: Why not do it in storyboard and look at the code it generates for you in the app delegate. Then you will see how it's done.  The first controller is the one you select in storyboard as the initial controller in the attribute inspector.

Comment: @rdelmar Leaving the default storyboard untouched as much as possible, performing everything in code. If it can be removed completely that would be best in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're starting with a controller in the storyboard, you only need to add two lines in the app delegate to embed that controller in a navigation controller. If you want to do it in code, I think this is the simplest way,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    return YES;
}
```

If you want to do it entirely in code, with no storyboard, then you need to create the window, the navigation controller, and its root view controller. You also need to click on the project icon in the files list, and in the "General" tab, delete the word "main" from the "Main Interface" pull down (that entry tells the system to start with a storyboard named "main.storyboard").

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    ViewController *vc = [ViewController new]; // You need to create this controller's view in its loadView method
    vc.title = @"Root View Controller";
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.window setRootViewController:nav];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```